# 2 UserDomainClass in Spring Security

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security, grails-orm

In the existing Grails application, I have 2 user domains, say UserAdmin and UserBasic. Both these domains have few common fields and also some distinct fields(respective to domain) and currently the login/logout is maintained using sessions for both types of users separately.  I want to integrate spring-security  in the existing application.

What would be the best approach to do it ? Considering that both domains also have different field. Can we inherit both the domains in a single domain and use it as Spring Security user class ? Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security Core uses one of the implementations of `UserDetails` interface as a projection of authenticated user. Grails provides e.g. `GrailsUser` class:

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/java/grails/plugin/springsecurity/userdetails/GrailsUser.java

Keep in mind, that this class is not a "domain" class in terms of Grails application layout - it does not get persisted in the database, it's just a projection of the user that is bounded to the current session.

If you have 2 different domain classes that represents users in your application, you can try to provide your own implementation of `UserDetailsService`, e.g.

```
class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        // 1. Check if expected user is type of UserBasic
        // 2. If not, check if expected user is type of UserAdmin
        // 3. If nothing found, throw an exception
        // 4. Otherwise create new GrailsUser instance using UserBasic or UserAdmin data
        // 5. Return created GrailsUser instance

        return null
    }
}
```

Then you have to inject your implementation by adding or modifying an entry in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` e.g.

```
// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    // other beans goes here
    // ...

    userDetailsService(CustomUserDetailsService)
}
```

This is just a concept that you can start from.